# Blank page when trying to do a facebook login inside an android webview app

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, webview

I developed an android webview application, and everything is workong fine. But inside the website you can login via a facebook button, which is working in all browsers, but not inside the webview app. Just when I click the facebook login button a blank page appears.

Others have quite similar problems like me, but they can load the facebook page instead of me.

I also tried it with these adds:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

and

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(myWebView, true);
}
```

I also want it to open internal, and then redirect automatically to my website's login page.

EDIT: 
Maybe I should also say that the facebook login page opens with a popup and that seems to be a problem.

Comment: Do you have the function shouldOverrideUrlLoading?

Comment: Yes, i am handling there how to opens ads or other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below code. You will get error response and you will get to know about the problem.

```
private void load webPage(){
        private WebView mWebview=null ;

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview.loadUrl("YOUR URL");
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }
}
```

Comment: what do i really have to add? if it is the onReceivedError, I tried but theres something wrong (red underlined).

Comment: @electromomo I have edited the code and I have passed context. Please check and let me know if it does work or not ?

Comment: thanks, i added it but nothing really happened. now we tried to change the fb button itself inside the website, now its opening a facebook page but there is written that the url is blocked.

Comment: Ok that could be happened as this page could be blocked by the Internet provider. If above answer is good for you then you can accept/upvote it.

Comment: i fixed the porblem with the whitelist now, but there is still the white page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the your code same as following

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView htmlWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        htmlWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        htmlWebView.loadUrl("https://inducesmile.com/blog");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I imported android.view.menu and menuitem, but there are still two errors because of the symbole "menu" in inflate(R...) and also "action_settings".

Comment: if you cannit used menu please remove it  which code is usefull to you only follow that section no problem

Comment: sorry then theres nothing usefull for me

Answer (score 0):

We just changed the facebook login site, it wont now appear inside a pop-up. Bute theres is still a small problem, afte you login in facebook it brings you back to the main login site. It seems that the login wasnt successfull, but it is. you have to go to the main site for example to see that you are logged in. Maybe someone knows why?